# How to use carrierwave to process an image that was directly uploaded to Amazon s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have the client upload an image directly to S3 with javascript and have designed the url to be exactly what it would be if carrierwave was uploading it (by using a unique_id that I pass to the create method). Once the image is uploaded, I want to send an AJAX request to create the record, and then process the image using carrierwave, but I don't need carrierwave to handle the upload, just process the versions.

I have this typical carrierwave setup using the fog gem for s3 storage:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  # . . .
end
```

and this:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/picture/#{model.unique_id}"
  end

  version :large do
    resize_to_limit(600, 600)
  end

  # . . .

end
```

But I can't figure out how to create a new `Picture` without carrierwave wanting to handle the upload.

I have tried setting Picture.image to the filename but it becomes nil:

```
>> Picture.create(image: params[:filename], unique_id: params[:unique_id])
=> #<Picture id: 96, image: nil, ... >
```

I have also tried getting the image by using carrierwave's "Uploading files from a remote location" feature:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController                                                                                  
  def create
    @picture = Picture.create(
      remote_image_url: params[:url],
      unique_id: params[:unique_id]
    ) 
   # . . . 
   end
  # . . .
end
```

That works eventually, but it is a lot of extra downloading and uploading and feels wrong.

How do I create the `Picture` without carrierwave getting involved, and then have carrierwave process the image versions?

Comment: have you find a solution ? can you please share it if so

Comment: I did eventually get everything working, though I tried so many different things along the way (and different combinations of techniques) that I can't even remember. I will have a close look soon and see if I can post something that explains how we have our system working now.

Comment: thank you I really appreciate that :)